# jquery smooth scroll incorrect result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm try to make smooth scrolling

but scrollbar not work as expect result it seem like smooth scrolling and default jump to # work on same time

here is my HTML (boot strap nav)

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light mb-3" id="main-nav">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#welcome">Welcome</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

here my js

```
<script>
    $('body').scrollspy({ 
      target: '#main-nav',
      offset: $('#main-nav').outerHeight()
    });

    // add smooth scrolling
    $('#main-nav a').on('click',(event) => {
      const sender = event.target; // sender 
      // check for a hash value
      if (sender.hash)
      {
        // prevent default behaviour
        event.preventDefault();

        // get sendar hash
        const hash = sender.hash;
        const navHeight = $('#main-nav').outerHeight();

        // animate smooth scroll
        $('html').animate({
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - (navHeight + 1),
        },1500,() => {
          // add hash to URL after scroll
          this.location.hash = hash;
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
```

and content of page

```
<section id="welcome">
    <h3>Welcome</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta eaque similique cupiditate! Pariatur, aliquid quae recusandae quidem atque cumque perspiciatis possimus quod repudiandae, labore nobis eius voluptatum! Impedit, sint in.
    </p>
</section>
<section id="about">
    <h3>About</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta eaque similique cupiditate! Pariatur, aliquid quae recusandae quidem atque cumque perspiciatis possimus quod repudiandae, labore nobis eius voluptatum! Impedit, sint in.
    </p>
</section>
<section id="services">
    <h3>Services</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta eaque similique cupiditate! Pariatur, aliquid quae recusandae quidem atque cumque perspiciatis possimus quod repudiandae, labore nobis eius voluptatum! Impedit, sint in.
    </p>
</section>
```

When I click link on `nav` for first time it's scroll nav bar over content header (make my header disapear)

[image]

but when I click same link again it's scroll up for a little and display as my expect result

[image]

So. Anyone know how to fix this problem to make scroll work correct at first time click

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code with change, add `padding-top:52px;` to `section` element and remove  `- (navHeight + 1)` from `$(hash).offset().top`.

```js
$('body').scrollspy({ 
      target: '#main-nav',
      offset: $('#main-nav').outerHeight()
    });

    // add smooth scrolling
    $('#main-nav a').on('click',(event) => {
      const sender = event.target; // sender 
      // check for a hash value
      if (sender.hash)
      {
        // prevent default behaviour
        event.preventDefault();

        // get sendar hash
        const hash = sender.hash;
        const navHeight = $('#main-nav').outerHeight();

        // animate smooth scroll
        $('html').animate({
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top,
        },1500,() => {
          // add hash to URL after scroll
          this.location.hash = hash;
        });
      }
    });
```

```css
section{
  min-height:500px;
  padding-top:52px;
}
#main-nav{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  top:0px;
  background:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light mb-3" id="main-nav">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#welcome">Welcome</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <section id="welcome">
    <h3>Welcome</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta eaque similique cupiditate! Pariatur, aliquid quae recusandae quidem atque cumque perspiciatis possimus quod repudiandae, labore nobis eius voluptatum! Impedit, sint in.
    </p>
</section>
<section id="about">
    <h3>About</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta eaque similique cupiditate! Pariatur, aliquid quae recusandae quidem atque cumque perspiciatis possimus quod repudiandae, labore nobis eius voluptatum! Impedit, sint in.
    </p>
</section>
<section id="services">
    <h3>Services</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta eaque similique cupiditate! Pariatur, aliquid quae recusandae quidem atque cumque perspiciatis possimus quod repudiandae, labore nobis eius voluptatum! Impedit, sint in.
    </p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/Vikaspatel/pen/jJZOYQ

please check this might be you get some help...

```js
  function div_slider(){
   $('ul li a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var attrval = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
    $('html,body').stop().animate({
     scrollTop: attrval.offset().top
    }, 1000)
   });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this bellow code to make easing scrollspy easily and very smoothly

```
<ul class="navigation clearfix">
    <li class=" "><a class="js-scroll-trigger nav-link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger nav-link" href="#about">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger nav-link" href="#amenities">Amenities</a></li>
    <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger nav-link" href="#plan">Floor Plan</a></li>
    <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger nav-link" href="#location">Location</a></li>
    <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>


<script src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script> (function ($) 
    { "use strict"; 
        $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function () 
        { 
            $('a.js-scroll-trigger').removeClass('active') 
            $(this).addClass('active'); 
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) 
            { 
                var target = $(this.hash); 
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']'); 
                if (target.length) 
                { 
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 72) }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo"); 
                    return false; 
                } 
            } 
        }); 
    })(jQuery); 
</script>
```